# Hide text as soon as page loads for a specific time then reveal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph that I would like to hide on page load until a period of time has passed. What would be the easiest way to do this? I understand that this'll probably involve js of some form but that's about as much as I can fathom.

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any kind of `<form>` for this. Just use the following snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $("p").hide().prop("hidden", false);
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("p").fadeIn(400);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p hidden>Welcome!</p>
```

The concept I am using is, load it hidden, programmatically hide it and the reveal after some time.

Comment: Whats is use of `hidden` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden). Google Bro!!! `:)`

Comment: Never came across this in last 3 years :P But it's **useful**!

Comment: @RayonDabre Came only an year ago I guess. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar But what is the purpose of using it here? There is very low chance OP was setting it

Comment: @A.Wolff: `The concept I am using is, load it hidden, programmatically hide it and the reveal after some time.`

Comment: @A.Wolff I didn't expect this from you, without reading it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm sorry, i should have read more carefully your answer ... :)

Comment: @A.Wolff, Its better to be o the safer side..Script may take few seconds to load and OP may not want that text to be displayed until script loads :)

Comment: @RayonDabre That's the reason I used it.

Comment: @RayonDabre Ya but to avoid it, i set CSS rule :)

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry, was I rude? `:)`

Comment: @A.Wolff Why take another rule and mess CSS up? We have HTML5 attributes. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I like for styling purpose to use CSS, not attribute :) It could be quite hard to debug it in some case. That's said, you get my vote...

Comment: @A.Wolff Rightly said. Agreed. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar That's said, this attribute **h**as its meaning and i'm very glad to learn a new thing, thanks Praveen!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a js bin where a text is hidden from users for 5 seconds using the `setTimeout` function.

http://jsbin.com/savoduruha/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple javascript code

```js
 function onTimerElapsed() {
   var myDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
   myDiv.style.display = myDiv.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
 }
```

```html
<body onload="setTimeout(onTimerElapsed, 2000);">
  <div id="theDiv" style="display:none;">
    Text to hide on reload
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It just could be done in CSS only:

```css
.toReveal {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: reveal 400ms 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<p class="toReveal">
  To reveal
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS solution would be to use keyframes. (no script library required!)

```css
p {opacity: 0;}
p {
 -webkit-animation: show-me-in-5-seconds 2s 1s forwards; 
  -moz-animation:    show-me-in-5-seconds 2s 1s forwards;
  -o-animation:      show-me-in-5-seconds 2s 1s forwards;
  animation:         show-me-in-5-seconds 2s 1s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes show-me-in-5-seconds {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes show-me-in-5-seconds {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes show-me-in-5-seconds {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes show-me-in-5-seconds {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<p>SHOW ME IN 5 SECONDS</p>
```